# Create normal mode command that accepts a number as an argument in Vim

Tags: vim

How do you create a normal mode command which accepts a number as part of it? Examples include `6>>` (indents 6 lines of text), `2dw` (deletes 2 words), and `23yy` (copies 23 lines to the copy buffer). Is there a way to do this using `nmap` or its ilk?

Specifically, I would like to create a mapping such that if I enter

```
<leader>4bu
```

in Normal mode, Vim will do

```
:4buf<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your own operator, see:

```
:help :map-operator
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `nnoremap`, not `nmap`.
2. Number supplied to last normal-mode command is accessible via `v:count` variable, so, for example, the following mapping will add supplied number to the buffer text number times:

   ```
   nnoremap ,a a<C-r>=v:count<CR><Esc>
   ```

   The reason why `20,a` will add `20` 20 times is because `20,a` is rewritten as `20a<C-r>...`. To avoid that you may use

   ```
   nnoremap ,a :<C-u>call feedkeys("a".v:count."\e", "n")<CR>
   ```

   . `<C-u>` will discard the count for the ex command but it is still accessible from `v:count` variable.